# When touch an ImageView i need to display the touched area in another ImageView in android?

Tags: android, image-processing

I used this method for that:

`croppedBitmap =Bitmap.createBitmap( sourceBitmap,  x,  y, 80, 80, mMatrix, true);`

But in corner areas it showing error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be >= 0`

Attached image is showing my expected Result

[image: Attached image is showing my expected Result]

Comment: before cropping, check the x and y arguments, if they are >=0, end if they aren't - crop smaller image, and draw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_imageview);
   imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int topParam =  imageView.getPaddingTop();
    int rightParam =  imageView.getPaddingRight();
    int maxTopParam = topParam+imageView.getMaxHeight();
    int maxRightParam = rightParam + imageView.getMaxWidth();
     if(event.getX>topParam&&event.getX<maxTopParam){
        //the x coordinate is in your image... do the same to Y
     }
      });
    return true;
    }
```