# How to Draw Portion of Bitmap via Canvas DrawBitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, border, drawbitmap

I have an
 [image: source condition]:

1. FrameLayout(marked with red)
2. Source ImageView(black)
3. Object(imageview) with OnTouchListener (orange)

Via **Object** with OnTouchListener,i want to show a portion of bitmap,that are filled on imageview(**source imageview**).

So it's not a problem,i'm doing like this:
`Bitmap bt = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,event.getX(),event.getY(),250,250);`

**where**:

1. **SourceBitmap** - is an image that are added to source ImageView
2. **event.getX()** / **event.getY()** is an coord,where i start to draw portion of bitmap
3. **250**,**250** - its an size of portion bitmap(part).

and the result is:

[image: result of first case]

So the problems occurs,when my object(with touchlistener),going to the border(i have made this possibility for **orange** object,to go **out** of border with Object.width()/2).

So in this case:
[image: case #2]
how can i achieve this result:
[image: excepted result of case #2]
where result of portion will be:

1. Part of bitmap
2. second part is color of framelayout background.

What i tried at current moment:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            //i want to draw bigger portion then corrds
            int CurrentX = (int)view.getX() - (view.getWidth());
            int CurrentY = (int)view.getY() - (view.getHeight());

            //case,when object is going out of border
            if(CurrentX <= 0)
            {
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle( Style.FILL  );
                paint.setColor( Color.RED );

                mBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(sourceBitmap,(int)view.getX() + Math.abs(CurrentX),(int)view.getY(),250,250);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,new Rect((int)view.getX()+Math.abs(CurrentX), (int)view.getY(),250-Math.abs(CurrentX),250),new RectF(Math.abs(CurrentX), 0, 250,250),paint);
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: for your `"How to Draw Portion of Bitmap via Canvas DrawBitmap"` question see: `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)` - """Draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill the destination rectangle. If the source rectangle is not null, it specifies the **subset of the bitmap to draw**."""

Comment: @pskink i tried and didn't get luck. Don't understand why.

Comment: @pskink this is  exactly what i need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405082/when-touch-an-imageview-i-need-to-display-the-touched-area-in-another-imageview . I Tried different variants with DrawBitmap and don't understand why,getting bad result

Comment: so what did you try? what is your code?

Comment: @pskink okay, ill add now my code snippets(but need a little bit time,because need to retranslate to java :) ).

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/ucHL6UAY)

Comment: @pskink thanks for the reply. But to be honest,it something another,because i have different imageviews(Dots) and i need to show portion of bitmap,via touch of this object,but not touch to the framelayout :).

Comment: sorry i have no green idea what you mean

Comment: can u share me working code for me @XTL.I have tried but i am getting erro like " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved by **myself**!
It was ***complicated***,but result is pretty nice.
Here we **go**:
So for my **case**(when object with OnTouchListener can go out of border  On X and Y axes),i've made **Post Conditions**(some kind of **regulations**).

---

### Conditions

**Width** = Width of *imageView*,where i want to show result.
**Height** = Height of *imageView*,where i want to show result;

### LeftSide

1. **X_Coord** < **0**  && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** < 0 && **Y_Coord** < **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Top Area**.
2. **X_Coord** < **0**  && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** > 0 && **Y_Coord** < **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Middle Area**.
3. **X_Coord** < **0**  && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** > 0 && **Y_Coord** > **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Bottom Area**.

---

### RightSide

1. **X_Coord** > **Bitmap.Height**  && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** > 0 && **Y_Coord** < **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Middle Area**.
2. **X_Coord** > **Bitmap.Height**  && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** < 0 && **Y_Coord** < **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Top Area**.
3. **X_Coord** > **Bitmap.Height**  && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** > 0 && **Y_Coord** > **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Bottom Area**.

---

### Standart(Area of Middle,that are not going to Left or Right side)

1. **X_Coord** - **Width / 2** > **0** && **X_Coord** < **Bitmap.Width**   && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** < 0 && **Y_Coord** < **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Top Area**.
2. **X_Coord** - **Width / 2** > **0** && **X_Coord** < **Bitmap.Width**   && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** > 0 && **Y_Coord** > **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Bottom Area**.
3. **X_Coord** - **Width / 2** > **0** && **X_Coord** < **Bitmap.Width**   && **Y_Coord** - **Height / 2** > 0 && **Y_Coord** < **Bitmap.Height**
   This is our **Middle Area**.

---

So via this "**Conditions**",i'm drawing portion of bitmap on my `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` case.
Let's see some example:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        int Width = ResultImgView.getWidth();
        int Height = ResultImgView.getHeight();
        //paint for our Red background
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle( Style.FILL  );
        paint.setColor( Color.RED );
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        Canvas canvas = null;

        //Our Condition 
        if(view.getX() - Width / 2 >= SourceBitmap.getWidth() 
            && view.getY() - Height / 2 > 0 && view.getY() + Height / 2 <  SourceBitmap.getHeight())
        {
            //Nice,we entered here. Seems that we're now located at RightSide at Middle position
            //So let's draw part of bitmap.
            //our margin for X coords
            int Difference = (int)((view.getX() - Width / 2 ) - SourceBitmap.getWidth();
            //dont forget to put margin
            //BTW we're now took portion of bitmap
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(SourceBitmap, ((int)view.getX() - Width / 2) - Difference, (int)view.getY() - Height / 2, Width,Height);
            canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            //draw rect
            canvas.drawRect(0,0,mBitmap.getWidth(),mBitmap.getHeight(),paint);
            //draw portion of bitmap
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,new Rect(Difference, 0,mBitmap.getWidth(),mBitmap.getHeight()),new Rect(0,0,mBitmap.getWidth() - Difference,mBitmap.getHeight()),null);
            //and that's all!
        }

        //do the same for other  condition....etc
        break;
}



   return true;
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: If you want to put some portion of android framework UI component (custom or built-in) in bitmap you can use its `onDraw` method with target canvas. View will be drawn starting at point (0, 0) so set right transformation and you can get any portion of UI.

Comment: @VallyN i solved my problem. Now ill post my solution.

Comment: just from my point of view keeping reference to internal View objects, if everything you want is just a part of how it looks on screen is a sure-proof method of getting problems later. Why not allowing component code to draw everything by itself?

Comment: @VallyN Thanks for the reply. I tried to make custom View and draw part of image in OnDraw Method,but it's not so comfortably. So with architecture and how i want to show portion of bitmap,i solved this with another way.

Answer (score 0):

If your `sourceBitmap` is just bitmap set into `ImageView` then result is predictable. To achieve your goal you need:

1. Orange square coordinates in coordinates of `FrameLayout`. Looks like you already have correct ones.
2. As `sourceBitmap` you have to use `Bitmap` created by your `FrameLayout.draw` method. Notice that your orange square have to be not `FrameLayout's` child.

If you post all of your code somewhere I can check it.

Comment: u menea k kajdomu obiektu(Orange square) prikru4en svoi listener(a ne v customnom frame-layout'e) i eti obiekti(orange square - iavliaiutsa imageview,kotorie dobavleni k framelayout -> AddView(orange obiekt)),t.e. oni childi :).  PS too much code to post here. Almost i resolved my problem,but i have strange behaviour with DrawCanvas method.